# Theads deadlock issue

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

**Env:**

```
  Wildfly 8.1
  Struts
  EJB 3.1
  Postgres 9
```

Facing a thread deadlock issue. Hoping to get some clarity.

**Code:**

- An action class calls two updates using an EJB

> ```
>  bean.writeLockedUpdate(o1) #1
>  ...
>  bean.writeLockedUpdate(o1) #2
> ```

- EJB bean's writeLockedUpdate(Object) does plain JDBC update via JPA

**Scenario:**

- UserRequestThread1 starts and completed #1 and doing some work within action class
- UserRequestThread2 started and acquired write lock on the bean and is inside bean.writeLockedUpdate(o1).

Both user threads trying to modify **same** o1 object.

Thread dump snip for those two threads:

**Thread1:**

> "default task-56" #558 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x724a4400 nid=0x1674
> waiting on condition [0x3d2ef000]    java.lang.Thread.State:
> TIMED_WAITING (parking)
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.EJBReadWriteLock$WriteLock.tryLock(EJBReadWriteLock.java:209)
>
> at Bean$$$view22.writeLockedUpdate(Unknown Source)

**Thread2:**

> "default task-43" #530 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x6bf10800 nid=0x15aa
> runnable [0x299c8000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE     at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
> at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
>
> at Bean$$$view22.writeLockedUpdate(Unknown Source)

**Possible explanation:**

I believe here is what happening.

1. thread2 having acquired bean write lock, is wating for DB row lock
2. thread1 having acquired DB row lock, is waiting for bean write lock

Jconsole doesnt show any deadlock. Guessing its because the second lock being blocked is at DB level

**Queation:**

Is there a way to verify the above explanation ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the confirmation from both Java and postgresql DB.

1. The thread dump clearly shows that thread1 is waiting for the EJB write lock
2. Following query on postgres reveals the operations that are blocked

> select bl.pid as blocked_pid, bl.mode as blocked_mode, a.usename as
>   blocked_user, ka.query as blocking_statement, now() - ka.query_start
>   as blocking_duration, kl.pid as blocking_pid, kl.mode as
>   blocking_mode, ka.usename as blocking_user, a.query as
>   blocked_statement, now() - a.query_start as blocked_duration from
>   pg_catalog.pg_locks bl join pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a on bl.pid =
>   a.pid join pg_catalog.pg_locks kl join pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity ka
>   on kl.pid = ka.pid on bl.transactionid = kl.transactionid and bl.pid
>   != kl.pid where not bl.granted

In my case the above query returns one row that shows that update is blocked

Thanks,
Rakesh